# How can I share the most viewed and/or highest rated documents from a document library on a page - modern sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am building a site and want to show the most viewed documents - as demonstrated in the site usage page - and also the highest rated documents from a list so visitors can quickly see the content that is useful to them.
I have tried many different ways and whilst I can display the whole list and put a filter on it, its not the most friendly way to show it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please use the 'Highlighted content' web part, you can set the source as 'a document library' and then use 'sort by' property which contains a "Most viewed" settings.

Here is the [Microsoft document for Highlighted Content web part](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-highlighted-content-web-part-e34199b0-ff1a-47fb-8f4d-dbcaed329efd) as a reference. Some screenshots below can help you.

[image]

[image]